# Camunda tomcat local host not working properly

Tags: spring-boot, maven, tomcat, localhost, camunda

Hey everyone so I've made a camunda project in spring tool suite using maven and I'm trying to open it up in camunda local host: 8080. I've put the war file for the project in the web apps folder and deployed it but when I start camunda 2 cmd's opens up and it has a lot of text but then it closes and only one is left open and when I go to the local host 8080 it shows the home screen but if I click on task list or anything it doesn't work anymore and says the site can't be reached. I've looked in the log files and this is what it says:

```
SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/camunda] threw exception
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngine.getManagementService()" because the return value of "org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.spi.ProcessEngineProvider.getProcessEngine(String)" is null
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.util.WebApplicationUtil.setWebapp(WebApplicationUtil.java:60)
        at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.engine.ProcessEnginesFilter.setWebappInTelemetry(ProcessEnginesFilter.java:283)
        at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.engine.ProcessEnginesFilter.serveIndexPage(ProcessEnginesFilter.java:270)
        at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.engine.ProcessEnginesFilter.serveIndexPage(ProcessEnginesFilter.java:188)
        at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.engine.ProcessEnginesFilter.applyFilter(ProcessEnginesFilter.java:127)
        at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.filter.AbstractTemplateFilter.doFilter(AbstractTemplateFilter.java:58)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.filter.headersec.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:89)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.filter.SessionCookieFilter.doFilter(SessionCookieFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.filter.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilterSecure(SecurityFilter.java:73)
        at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.auth.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:62)
        at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.auth.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:60)
        at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.SecurityActions.runWithAuthentications(SecurityActions.java:44)
        at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.auth.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:60)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:359)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1735)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

What does this error mean and what can I do to fix it so that it works?

Answer (score 0):

".getProcessEngine(String)" is null a" means the process engine did not boostrap correctly. Search further in the console output to find the underlying reason. Could be e.g. something related to the DB connection.

Alternatively create the project with https://start.camunda.com/